# Remove element from DOM with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a form and try to delete it on button click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="remove()">remove</button>

    <form action="test.html" class="contactForm" dir="ltr" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <ol>
            <li class="csc-form-9 csc-form-element csc-form-element-textline">
                <label for="field-9">Vorname</label>
                <input class="inputFormText" id="field-9" name="tx_form[firstname]" type="text"/>
            </li>
            <li class="csc-form-10 csc-form-element csc-form-element-textline">
                <label for="field-10">Nachname</label>
                <input class="inputFormText" id="field-10" name="tx_form[lastname]" type="text"/>
            </li>

        </ol>
    </form>

    <script>
    function remove()
    {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contactForm");

        console.log(x);

        x.remove();
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

According to [this article](http://red-team-design.com/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/) it should be possible by just calling `remove()` on the DOM element. However, I get:

> (index):30 Uncaught TypeError: x.remove is not a function
>       at remove ((index):30)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):7)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method returns an array-like collection of elements, so get the element by index.

```
x[0].remove();
```

---

Or use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method to get a single element.

```
var x = document.querySelector(".contactForm");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contactForm")[0];
```